# Angular 2+: How to show a message if not logged In irrespective of the page I am in

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Angular 2+ : Want to give a snackbar message saying that 'please login to view more customized view'.

Scenario: 
1. User is opening any app url (it can be user shared news article link, home page or any page)
2. If the user is not logged in (no valid key exists), show a message (like a material snackbar message) at the bottom saying that plz login to view more customized view.

3. This message will be available for 5 sec and then it should disappear.
4. after that no need of showing this message on any page.

(if the above is not feasible - a message on all pages should also be fine).

any suggestions plz??

Comment: can you draw (even if by hand) what UX exactly you want. I guess you want sort of cross page persistent bar in the ui that hints user to login to get more stuff?

Comment: that is almost right. If user has not logged in and a page(any page) first time, just gently display a message at the bottom saying that plz login.

Comment: so if you can add clarifications - I can help;)

Comment: for example in ionic this is fairly simple to achieve by working with app.ts / app.html - sort of root page that does side menu etc. Now with Angular - probably you need to share details around basic structure that you have in your app.

Comment: I have app.component.html without <router-outlet>, you are suggesting having a component below the router outlet that checks for the login and display the message.

Comment: Yes I would start with this sort of root page view and see if you can implement it there. I saw an example of the app where in the top panel below the status bar app had "^" button which worked across all pages consistently and when I looked into that implementation it was done in app.html. But this was Ionic which can slightly differ in the approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution is really simple. Add a component to check the authstate, if not logged in display it on the page and fix it at the bottom of the view port.

app.component.html

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<custom-auth-mes-display-component *ngIf="!isUserLoggedIn"></custom-auth-mes-display-component>,
```